# How to mount a Google Drive folder on R jupyter notebook in Google Colab?

Tags: r, google-drive-api, jupyter-notebook, mount, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to access Google Drive files from R jupyter notebook in Google Colab?

I am looking for an equivalent R package or code like this:

```
from google.colab import drive


drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Anyway, as a workaround, I run this code from a python notebook and can access the drive from R notebook but curious if there is R package from Google.

Thanks.

Comment: Whis is this downvoted?  Using Google Colab for R instruction seems like a perfectly reasonable choice for those with access to Gsuite.

Comment: There is an R package from rstudio called [googledrive](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/), I've been meaning to test it out. From the documentation on Google Colab there is, as of yet, no support for drive mounting in R notebooks, but I see no reason why the interface with the package shouldn't work.

Comment: Just to complement my last comment. There is no official package from google nor news of when it might come. But you can use this neat one-liner from Thong Nguyen:
cat(system('python3 -c "from google.colab import drive\ndrive.mount()"', intern=TRUE), sep='\n', wait=TRUE)

Comment: Hi, @MAIAkoVSky can you elaborate in your recommendation? I tried your batch approach and also the reticulate to insert python code... no one show the url to get the authentication code (shown in google colab on python kernel)... Your approach return " had status 1”...

Comment: You can check out my answer on a similar question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59746036/how-to-read-data-from-google-drive-using-r-in-colab/61925911#61925911

The slightly longer answer is that there is no "official way" to link your google drive to your rsession in colab, but you can work around it by running python code. I tried this months ago and haven't used it since, so I can't confirm whether it still works.