# in Google Colab how do you find the path to a file in Google Drive. I'm using R

Tags: r, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Drive to store my data files (csv and JSON) and Google Colab to write and run a notebook using R.  I cannot figure out how to find the path to my data files for read.csv, etc.

I've tried various methods.  I put the csv file into the same folder with the Colab notebook.  In RStudio I would then only have to type:

```
metadata <- read.csv("Metadata_pipe_delimited.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "|")
```

That doesn't work in Colab.

I've tried getting the shareable link and pulling out the ID from that.  The ID does not work.

I've tried getwd() to find that it is '/content' and I've used that to preface my file name.  That didn't work.

I've tried variations such as:

```
metadata <- read.csv("drive/My Drive/CSC 7810 Project/Metadata_pipe_delimited.csv", header = TRUE, quote = "", sep = "|")

metadata <- read.csv("/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/CSC 7810 Project/Metadata_pipe_delimited.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "|")

metadata <- read.csv("/content/CSC 7810 Project/Metadata_pipe_delimited.csv", header = TRUE, sep = "|")

metadata <- read.csv("1hG8Q-MDpDfx6I37dxj_aM15v9SQNlDAG", header = TRUE, sep = "|")
```

This last one contains the ID from the shareable link.  None of these has worked.

Does anyone know how to find the path for a file in Google Drive or how to import a file into R when using Colab?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not familiar with Colab, but would the googledrive package help? https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/

Comment: I don't know.  I'll try it.  Thank you.

Comment: -- after reading that link and trying it, I suspect its for use in things like RStudio to see files in my Google Drive.  Unfortunately I'm in Google Colab.  I'm using Colab because we have so many large files we need to process, we thought Colab would handle them better than our laptops while also allowing us to collaborate on the code.

Comment: Google Colab does provide an option to mount the google drive in the Python Kernel. So probably you could use a Python kernel, mount the drive and run R within the same notebook using rpy2

Comment: I've posted an answer to this question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61925911/11683685, where I explain how you can do what @James is suggesting.